# log4js appenders with different levels of logging levels

Tags: node.js, log4j, winston, log4js-node

I'm trying to create a logger configuration which logs only "**ERROR**" level information to console and "**DEBUG**" level information to file appenders.
Can anyone help on how to create a logger with above config?

Thanks in advance. Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 11):

```
var log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    everything: { type: 'stdout' },
    file_log: { type: 'file', filename: 'anyPath/all-logs.log' },
    logLevelFilter: {
      type: 'logLevelFilter',
      level: 'debug',
      appender: 'file_log',
    },
  },
  categories: {
    default: {
      appenders: ['logLevelFilter', 'everything'],
      level: 'all',
    },
  },
});
const logger = log4js.getLogger();
```

in this example all logs will be shown in the console , but only ***debug*** level and  above will be add to the *anyPath/all-logs.log* file

Comment: official documentation:
https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/master/docs/logLevelFilter.md

Comment: Agree. I dont see a straightfoward way to configure except using 'logLevelFilter' to point to another appender. It will be great if one category can specify different log levels for different appenders. (I dont need have extra "someSmartRedirectAppender" in order to use an appender with different log level.)

Answer (score 0):

For ERROR in console, you can directly have console.log statements. For DEBUG, you can add that in your config feel like below-

```
const log4js = require('log4js'); // include log4js
log4js.configure({
  appenders: { app: { type: 'file', filename: 'app.log' } },
  categories: { default: { appenders: ['app'], level: 'debug' } }
});

const logger = log4js.getLogger('app');
logger.debug('Your debug message');
```

You need to provide the level category inside categories in your config file.

Hope this should help.